# PHP cannot read cookies from Chrome in certain cases

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies

This issue appeared today and it seems to have something to do with webkit.

**On pages that redirect via location [301/302] HTTP headers (404 error pages in this case) PHP cannot read the cookies - meaning the $_COOKIE is an empty array.**

I'm aware of the webkit bug that using Set-Cookie and Location header in the same response breaks, but this is about reading not writing so it's supposed to be in the request headers.

I'm using the latest Chrome v26. On the backend I have PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 on my home server, and the exact same on a production server (which i did not set up and it's not on default settings). On the production server I cannot read the cookies as I said before but on my home/dev server I can.

And it gets worse: On another server which runs PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 I also can't read the cookies if the Content-Type header is not html, but text/plain.

I set the cookies the following way:

```
if (setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, null, isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']), $httponly))
{
    $_COOKIE[$name] = $value;
    return true;
}
return false;
```

- $httponly is false
- $path is '/'
- the name consists of lowercase letters
- the value consists of numbers and dashes

I can see the cookie in the Developer Tools / Resources tab and it works fine on simple html pages.

I appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: The quick workaround was not to save new and empty sessions.But the problem still exists.

Comment: Can we see an actual setcookie call (i.e. all the values), please?

Comment: setcookie('lwcsessid', '1367271447-42780100-18814-62545', null, '/', null, isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']), false);
As i said the cookies are set and can be read on pages that do not redirect. I also tried specifying an expiration date instead of leaving it to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

the redirect page and the redirector page are at the same domain? Maybe this can being considered as a XSS attempt to stealing cookies. Try to send "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" );
```

Comment: They are. Even in the same document root. I think this is because of Chrome's prefetch feature.

Comment: this can be related with the [Do Not Track](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Not_Track). Try to disable it in your browser.

Comment: It was never enabled. There are no special request headers, only the usual Accept-*, Cache-Control, Connection, Host, User-Agent, Referer,
and Cookie except on redirected pages.

Comment: you can try to force the setting of cookies at redirector page. Use getallheaders() to read the cookies and then set with header("Set-Cookie: "). You can do this immediatly before the "Location" header.

Comment: $headers = getallheaders();
header("Set-Cookie: ". $headers["Cookie"]. "; path=/");

Comment: Thanks but this does not work either and I don't see why should it. It just overrides the Cookie header with itself if it's not already sent.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was with `session_set_cookie_params()`, the parameter for the domain (the 3rd argument) was prefixed with a period `.`, such as ".localhost".  When I removed the `.`, $_COOKIE variable was populated.